# WCF Load testing with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate

Tags: .net, wcf, visual-studio-2010, iis, load-testing

I am looking for a tutorials how to write those tests.
I am hosting my WCF service at IIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take a look at the WCF Load Testing tool on CodePlex [here](http://wcfloadtest.codeplex.com/releases/view/51762).  This will take the sequence of a trace file created by the WCF service and replicate it into a use case.  Look [here](http://devmatter.blogspot.com/2010/06/wcf-load-test-beta-for-visual-studio.html) as well.  Here's a good [sample](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2010/12/03/generating-load-tests-for-wcf-services-with-the-wcf-load-test-tool.aspx) of the WCF Load Testing Tool.  I've also heard of [wcfstorm](http://www.wcfstorm.com/wcf/home.aspx) but have never used it before.